# How to check if a pallet can be compiled to no-std/WASM?

Tags: pallet, wasm, no-std

How to check if a pallet can be compiled to no-std/WASM?

I ran:

```sh
cargo build --no-default-features --target wasm32-unknown-unknown
```

But this didn't work. IIUC, we need some ENV to build the pallet to WASM.

And I don't want to add this pallet to runtime and build the entire runtime to verify this, which takes a lot of time each time.

I can compile the entire runtime, but if I try to compile the pallet with the command above, I got:

```rs
The following warnings were emitted during compilation:

warning: src/helpers.c:1:10: fatal error: 'setjmp.h' file not found
warning: #include <setjmp.h>
warning:          ^~~~~~~~~~
warning: 1 error generated.

error: failed to run custom build command for `wasmtime-runtime v1.0.2`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/root/code/darwinia-network/darwinia/target/debug/build/wasmtime-runtime-d7265199eb92a3b8/build-script-build` (exit status: 1)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rerun-if-changed=src/helpers.c
  TARGET = Some("wasm32-unknown-unknown")
  OPT_LEVEL = Some("0")
  HOST = Some("x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu")
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC_wasm32-unknown-unknown
  CC_wasm32-unknown-unknown = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC_wasm32_unknown_unknown
  CC_wasm32_unknown_unknown = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=TARGET_CC
  TARGET_CC = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC
  CC = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CFLAGS_wasm32-unknown-unknown
  CFLAGS_wasm32-unknown-unknown = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CFLAGS_wasm32_unknown_unknown
  CFLAGS_wasm32_unknown_unknown = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=TARGET_CFLAGS
  TARGET_CFLAGS = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CFLAGS
  CFLAGS = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS
  CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
  DEBUG = Some("true")
  running: "clang" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-g" "-fno-omit-frame-pointer" "--target=wasm32-unknown-unknown" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-DCFG_TARGET_OS_unknown" "-DCFG_TARGET_ARCH_wasm32" "-o" "/root/code/darwinia-network/darwinia/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/debug/build/wasmtime-runtime-3f0543a6492357d6/out/src/helpers.o" "-c" "src/helpers.c"
  cargo:warning=src/helpers.c:1:10: fatal error: 'setjmp.h' file not found
  cargo:warning=#include <setjmp.h>
  cargo:warning=         ^~~~~~~~~~
  cargo:warning=1 error generated.
  exit status: 1

  --- stderr


  error occurred: Command "clang" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-g" "-fno-omit-frame-pointer" "--target=wasm32-unknown-unknown" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-DCFG_TARGET_OS_unknown" "-DCFG_TARGET_ARCH_wasm32" "-o" "/root/code/darwinia-network/darwinia/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/debug/build/wasmtime-runtime-3f0543a6492357d6/out/src/helpers.o" "-c" "src/helpers.c" with args "clang" did not execute successfully (status code exit status: 1).


warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
```

---

I added the `setjmp.h` to the path. And the problem above was resolved.

But I got a lot of `xxx not found` issues. And I realized those `.h` are all `lib32`. So, I believe we need an ENV to compile this. `x86_64` host can not compile this natively.

Comment: why not use a simple mock runtime?

Comment: I still feel it isn't very easy.

Comment: The command you posted should work. What kind of error did you get?

Comment: @bkchr updated my question.

Comment: could you use `cargo check` https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-check.html instead of `cargo build`?

Comment: I have already tried that. Same result.