# Compiling runtime with std targeting wasm32-unknown-unknown

Tags: wasm

We are exploring how to wrap part of the runtime logic into a re-usable WASM blob that can be wrapped in a JS library.
To do that, we are investigating using `wasm-pack` and `wasm-bindgen`. Unfortunately, `wasm-bindgen` does not support compiling for `no_std` environment, hence we are in the need of using the `std` feature while targeting the `wasm32-unknown-unknown` architecture.

As I see, this does not currently seem to be possible because of the assumption that compiling for `wasm32-unknown-unknown` means compiling the runtime, which in this case is not true.
Is there a way to do this? Or is bugging `wasm-bindgen` people to support `no_std` the best shot we have?

```rs
error: the wasm32-unknown-unknown target is not supported by default, you may need to enable the "js" feature. For more information see: https://docs.rs/getrandom/#webassembly-support
   --> /home/dev/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/getrandom-0.2.8/src/lib.rs:263:9
    |
263 | /         compile_error!("the wasm32-unknown-unknown target is not supported ...
264 | |                         default, you may need to enable the \"js\" feature...
265 | |                         For more information see: \
266 | |                         https://docs.rs/getrandom/#webassembly-support...
    | |________________________________________________________________________^

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module `imp`
   --> /home/dev/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/getrandom-0.2.8/src/lib.rs:290:5
    |
290 |     imp::getrandom_inner(dest)
    |     ^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `imp`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0433`.
error: could not compile `getrandom` (lib) due to 2 previous errors
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
```

Comment: I have the same question. https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/7710/how-to-check-if-a-pallet-can-be-compiled-to-no-std-wasm

Comment: Hey, I see your question is trying to compile the runtime without the default features. I am trying to compiling with the std feature, so it's not really the same question...

Comment: The runtime is already a WASM blob, it is located in `target/release/wbuild/polkadot-runtime/polkadot_runtime.wasm`. How is your use-case different?

Comment: `wasm-bindgen` requires `std`, hence the only way to expose the runtime blob to JS is by building a second WASM blob with `std` support that wraps around the runtime blob. So I was wondering wether the runtime itself can already by compiled with `std` support and is hence supported in `wasm-bindgen`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should extract that logic out.

For example,

`pallet-a -> pallet-a + primitives-a/impls-a`. Get rid of the pallet/runtime framework. Then compile the `primitives-a/impls-a` to WASM.

Comment: Yes, that is definitely something to do  But compiling even just a simple crate that only depends on `codec`, `scale-info` and `sp-std` fails if the combination of `--features std` and `target wasm32-unknown-unknown` is used, so I assume by design it's not possible to target WASM with `std` feature on, at least not in a way that I would be able to understand.

Comment: You can only enable a few std things in the WASM, and you need to tweak it yourself. Because it is WASM, it runs in the browser in the sandbox. For example, there is no `std::io` at all in that envoiroment. So, you can't just enable the std directly.

Comment: My understanding is that you can decide how much "sandboxed" you want your WASM to be. There could be cases where it makes sense to have `std` capabilities in a WASM executable. But as far as I understand Parity does not support that case in any way.

Comment: So, you'd better ask this in the Rust WASM community? It looks like it's a general question. Sorry, I have no more idea about this.